# Calculating number of permutations with exclusion criterion in Matlab

Tags: algorithm, math, permutation

I have a wordlist of 12 items, consisting of 4 semantic categories with 3 items in each category. This includes couch, shelf, table (furniture), plane, boat, truck (vehicles), Jacket, shoes, sweater (clothes), lettuce, carrot, spinach (Vegetables). I need to produce a randomised list with these 12 items, however there are some rules.

Firstly, items from the same semantic category cannot neighbour each other in the list (e.g lettuce and spinach). Second, the list is divided into 3 blocks (items 1-4, 5-8 and 9-12). In each block, there must be at least, but no more, than one item from each semantic category.

The implementation should be in Matlab

Comment: I know how to do this in Python, but I don't know Matlab. Do you think that you can translate it?

Comment: Each block has 4 elements and there are exactly 4 categories, so "In each block, there must be atleast but no more than one item from each semantic category" is just a convoluted way to say "in each block there must be exactly one item from each category".

Answer (score 2):

After thought, I'll just give pseudocode. And make it look Matlab-like enough that you can probably figure out how to make it work.

First, your words can be arranged in an array of arrays. Like this.

```
word_lists = [
    ["couch", "shelf", "table"],
    ["plane", "boat", "truck"],
    ["jacket", "shoes", "sweater"],
    ["lettuce", "carrot", "spinach"]]
```

Let's scramble each internal list. I'm guessing the syntax is something like this:

```
for i = 1:4
    word_lists[i] = word_lists[i](randperm(3))
end
```

Now let's choose the choices of lists. (Each list is one category.)

```
list_choices = [randperm(4), randperm(4), randperm(4)]
```

But there can be a problem. We might have the last list choice in the one group be the same as the first list choice in the next group. Fix that.

```
while list_choices(1, 4) == listchoices(2, 1)
    list_choices(2) = randperm(4)
end

while list_choices(2, 4) == listchoices(3, 1)
    list_choices(3) = randperm(4)
end
```

And now extract your wordlist. If I have the indexing rules right it should be something like this:

```
word_list = cat(1,
                word_lists(list_choices(1), 1),
                word_lists(list_choices(2), 2),
                word_lists(list_choices(3), 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following procedure will produce a list that satisfies the adjacency requirement. It represents a pseudo-random sample from all such lists due to the the symmetry of the underlying conditional probability calculations.

```
word_lists = [
  ["couch", "shelf", "table"],
  ["plane", "boat", "truck"],
  ["jacket", "shoes", "sweater"],
  ["lettuce", "carrot", "spinach"]
]
```

`word_lists`, and each element (array) thereof, can of course be of any size.

---

We begin by creating an array from `word_lists` that saves the category offsets with each element of each category:

```
[[["couch", 0], ["shelf", 0], ["table", 0]],
 [["plane", 1], ["boat", 1], ["truck", 1]],
 [["jacket", 2], ["shoes", 2], ["sweater", 2]],
 [["lettuce", 3], ["carrot", 3], ["spinach", 3]]]
```

Next, each element (array) of this array can be shuffled:

```
[[["shelf", 0], ["table", 0], ["couch", 0]],
 [["boat", 1], ["plane", 1], ["truck", 1]],
 [["sweater", 2], ["shoes", 2], ["jacket", 2]],
 [["carrot", 3], ["spinach", 3], ["lettuce", 3]]]3
```

Now take the transpose of this array:

```
[[["couch", 0], ["plane", 1], ["jacket", 2], ["lettuce", 3]],
 [["shelf", 0], ["boat", 1], ["shoes", 2], ["carrot", 3]], 
 [["table", 0], ["truck", 1], ["sweater", 2], ["spinach", 3]]]
```

Next, shuffle the elements in each row:

```
arr
  #=> [[["lettuce", 3], ["plane", 1], ["jacket", 2], ["couch", 0]],
  #    [["shelf", 0], ["boat", 1], ["carrot", 3], ["shoes", 2]], 
  #    [["truck", 1], ["sweater", 2], ["table", 0], ["spinach", 3]]]
```

---

If we were to partially flatten this array in preparation to producing the randomized list we would obtain:

```
[["lettuce", 3], ["plane", 1], ["jacket", 2], ["couch", 0], 
 ["shelf", 0], ["boat", 1], ["carrot", 3], ["shoes", 2],
 ["truck", 1], ["sweater", 2], ["table", 0], ["spinach", 3]]
```

This does not meet requirements, however, as `"shelf"` follows `"couch"`, both being in the same category (offset `0` in `word_lists`).

We need to first compare

```
(arr[0].last).last #=> ["couch", 0].last => 0
```

with

```
(arr[1].first).last #=> ["shelf", 0].last => 0
```

Since these values are the same we need to randomly reposition `["shelf", 0]` in

```
arr[1]
  #=> [["shelf", 0], ["boat", 1], ["carrot", 3], ["shoes", 2]]
```

We can do that by randomly selecting an index between `1` and `3` and inserting it after element `arr[1][i]`. Suppose the random index were `2`. We would then have:

```
[["shelf", 0], ["boat", 1], ["carrot", 3], ["shelf", 0], ["shoes", 2]]
```

Of course we would have to remove the first element of this array to obtain:

```
[["boat", 1], ["carrot", 3], ["shelf", 0], ["shoes", 2]]
```

We then have

```
arr
  #=> [[["lettuce", 3], ["plane", 1], ["jacket", 2], ["couch", 0]],
  #    [["boat", 1], ["carrot", 3], ["shelf", 0], ["shoes", 2]],
  #    [["truck", 1], ["sweater", 2], ["table", 0], ["spinach", 3]]]
```

Since

```
(arr[1].last).last #=> ["shoes", 2].last #=> 2
```

and

```
(arr[2].first).last #=> ["truck", 1].last #=> 1
```

differ, there is no need to reposition `["truck", 1]` in `arr[2]`.<sup>1</sup>

We can now partially flatten `arr` to obtain

```
[["lettuce", 3], ["plane", 1], ["jacket", 2], ["couch", 0],
 ["shelf", 0], ["boat", 1], ["carrot", 3], ["shoes", 2],
 ["truck", 1], ["sweater", 2], ["table", 0], ["spinach", 3]]
```

and then map each element of this array (an array) into that element's first value, to obtain a pseudo-random list that meets the adjacency requirement:

```
["lettuce", "plane", "jacket", "couch",
 "shelf", "boat", "carrot", "shoes",
 "truck", "sweater", "table", "spinach"]
```

<sup>1. Note that if `["shelf", 0]` had been randomly moved to the end of `arr[1]` in the previous step and the first element of `arr[2]` had been `["table", 0]` (rather than `["truck", 1]`), the latter would have had to be moved in `arr[2]`</sup>.